# .ipynb Github preview upload error: "Invalid Notebook 'name' is a required property"

Tags: json, git, github, jupyter-notebook, github-actions

I'm getting the following error when I upload my python notebook from Google Colab to Github and was wondering if someone could help.

I have tried to edit the file in nvim to include the name property in the metadata as:

```
"name": "SMS_Text_Classification_v2"
```

However, Github doesn't seem to recognize the name property I added. When I run the program on Google Colab it works out perfectly.

Any ideas?

**[Error]:** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6E5l.png)

**Entire Code:**

```
{
  "cells": [
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "execution_count": null,
      "metadata": {
        "id": "8RZOuS9LWQvv"
      },
      "outputs": [],
      "source": [
        "# import libraries\n",
        "import tensorflow as tf\n",
        "import pandas as pd\n",
        "from tensorflow import keras\n",
        "\n",
        "import tensorflow_datasets as tfds\n",
        "import numpy as np\n",
        "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n",
        "\n",
        "print(tf.__version__)"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "execution_count": null,
      "metadata": {
        "id": "lMHwYXHXCar3"
      },
      "outputs": [],
      "source": [
        "# get data files\n",
        "!wget https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/project-data/sms/train-data.tsv\n",
        "!wget https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/project-data/sms/valid-data.tsv\n",
        "\n",
        "train_file_path = \"train-data.tsv\"\n",
        "test_file_path = \"valid-data.tsv\""
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "execution_count": null,
      "metadata": {
        "id": "g_h508FEClxO"
      },
      "outputs": [],
      "source": [
        "# Reading Data & Setting Column Labels\n",
        "train_data = pd.read_table(train_file_path, header=None, names=[\"spam\", \"message\"])\n",
        "test_data = pd.read_table(test_file_path, header=None, names=[\"spam\", \"message\"])\n",
        "\n",
        "train_data.head()"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Converting Categorical Data to Integers\n",
        "train_data[\"spam\"] = train_data[\"spam\"].replace({\"ham\": 0, \"spam\": 1})\n",
        "test_data[\"spam\"] = test_data[\"spam\"].replace({\"ham\": 0, \"spam\": 1})\n",
        "train_data[\"spam\"].value_counts()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "ayceFwPomUoP"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Modeling HamOrSpam Data\n",
        "import seaborn as sns\n",
        "\n",
        "sns.countplot(x='spam', data=train_data)\n",
        "plt.show()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "abkdtTUUmNwI"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Calculating HamOrSpam & Creating Data Frame\n",
        "ham_msg = train_data[train_data[\"spam\"] == 0]\n",
        "neg = ham_msg.shape[0]\n",
        "print(f\"negative: {neg}\")\n",
        "\n",
        "spam_msg = train_data[train_data[\"spam\"] == 1]\n",
        "pos = spam_msg.shape[0]\n",
        "print(f\"positive: {pos}\")\n",
        "\n",
        "total = neg + pos\n",
        "print(f\"total: {total}\")\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data = train_data"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "QezoXyGUmXsp"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Cleaning Data: Removing Punctuation\n",
        "\n",
        "import string\n",
        "punctuations_list = string.punctuation\n",
        "def remove_punctuations(text):\n",
        "    temp = str.maketrans('', '', punctuations_list)\n",
        "    return text.translate(temp)\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data['message'] = balanced_data['message'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuations(x))\n",
        "\n",
        "# Perform the same pre-processing on test data as on training data.\n",
        "test_data['message'] = test_data['message'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuations(x))\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data.head()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "9PCcR1zImZ2K"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Cleaning Data: Removing Stop Words\n",
        "\n",
        "import nltk\n",
        "from nltk.corpus import stopwords\n",
        "nltk.download('stopwords')\n",
        "\n",
        "stop_words = stopwords.words('english')\n",
        "new_stopwords = [\"u\", \"ur\"]\n",
        "stop_words.extend(new_stopwords)\n",
        "\n",
        "def remove_stopwords(text):\n",
        "    imp_words = []\n",
        "\n",
        "    # Storing the important words\n",
        "    for word in str(text).split():\n",
        "        word = word.lower()\n",
        "\n",
        "        if word not in stop_words:\n",
        "            imp_words.append(word)\n",
        "\n",
        "    output = \" \".join(imp_words)\n",
        "\n",
        "    return output\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data['message'] = balanced_data['message'].apply(lambda text: remove_stopwords(text))\n",
        "\n",
        "# Perform the same pre-processing on test data as on training data.\n",
        "test_data['message'] = test_data['message'].apply(lambda text: remove_stopwords(text))\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data.head()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "ZVecOSFhmc0k"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Displaying Data as WordCloud\n",
        "\n",
        "from wordcloud import WordCloud\n",
        "def plot_word_cloud(data, typ):\n",
        "    email_corpus = \" \".join(data['message'])\n",
        "\n",
        "    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))\n",
        "\n",
        "    wc = WordCloud(\n",
        "        background_color='black',\n",
        "        max_words=100,\n",
        "        width=800,\n",
        "        height=400,\n",
        "        collocations=False\n",
        "    ).generate(email_corpus)\n",
        "\n",
        "    plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')\n",
        "    plt.title(f'WordCloud for {typ} emails', fontsize=15)\n",
        "    plt.axis('off')\n",
        "    plt.show()\n",
        "\n",
        "plot_word_cloud(balanced_data[balanced_data['spam'] == 0], typ='Non-Spam')\n",
        "plot_word_cloud(balanced_data[balanced_data['spam'] == 1], typ='Spam')"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "CdEZWCBwmf5Q"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Removing Spam Classification Column\n",
        "\n",
        "train_labels = balanced_data.pop(\"spam\")\n",
        "test_labels = test_data.pop(\"spam\")\n",
        "\n",
        "balanced_data"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "PwzsZjEgmht2"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Converting Message Column into Numpy Array\n",
        "\n",
        "train_X = balanced_data[\"message\"].to_numpy()\n",
        "train_Y = train_labels.to_numpy()\n",
        "test_X = test_data[\"message\"].to_numpy()\n",
        "test_Y = test_labels.to_numpy()\n",
        "train_X"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "5kuahVFTmjUo"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Tokenizing & Padding Text\n",
        "\n",
        "from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer\n",
        "from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences\n",
        "\n",
        "# Tokenize the text data\n",
        "tokenizer = Tokenizer()\n",
        "tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_X)\n",
        "\n",
        "# Convert text to sequences\n",
        "train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X)\n",
        "test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_X)\n",
        "\n",
        "# Pad sequences to have the same length\n",
        "max_len = 100\n",
        "\n",
        "train_sequences = pad_sequences(\n",
        "    train_sequences,\n",
        "    maxlen=max_len,\n",
        "    padding='post',\n",
        "    truncating='post'\n",
        ")\n",
        "test_sequences = pad_sequences(\n",
        "    test_sequences,\n",
        "    maxlen=max_len,\n",
        "    padding='post',\n",
        "    truncating='post'\n",
        ")\n",
        "print(train_sequences[0])"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "MBVyrX5VmlTo"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Build the model\n",
        "model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([\n",
        "    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(\n",
        "        input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1,\n",
        "        output_dim=32,\n",
        "        mask_zero=True,\n",
        "    ),\n",
        "    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),\n",
        "    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),\n",
        "    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),\n",
        "    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')\n",
        "])\n",
        "\n",
        "# Print the model summary\n",
        "model.summary()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "61DOzInBmrqd"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Compiling Model\n",
        "\n",
        "model.compile(\n",
        "    loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),\n",
        "    metrics=['accuracy'],\n",
        "    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)\n",
        ")"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "pbl3Da2vsG4O"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Setting up Early Stopping & Reducing Learning Rate to reduce Overfitting\n",
        "\n",
        "from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau\n",
        "# callback\n",
        "es = EarlyStopping(\n",
        "    patience=4,\n",
        "    monitor = 'val_accuracy',\n",
        "    restore_best_weights = True\n",
        ")\n",
        "\n",
        "lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(\n",
        "    patience = 2,\n",
        "    monitor = 'val_loss',\n",
        "    factor = 0.2,\n",
        "    verbose = 1\n",
        ")\n",
        "\n",
        "# Weights\n",
        "weight_for_0 = (1 / neg) * (total / 2.0)\n",
        "weight_for_1 = (1 / pos) * (total / 2.0)\n",
        "\n",
        "class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}\n",
        "\n",
        "# Training\n",
        "history = model.fit(\n",
        "    x=train_sequences,\n",
        "    y=train_Y,\n",
        "    validation_split=0.1,\n",
        "    epochs=20,\n",
        "    batch_size=32,\n",
        "    callbacks = [lr, es],\n",
        "    class_weight=class_weight\n",
        ")"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "pclTMQGlsJgr"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Displaying Model Accuracy over Epochs\n",
        "\n",
        "plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')\n",
        "plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')\n",
        "plt.title('Model Accuracy')\n",
        "plt.ylabel('Accuracy')\n",
        "plt.xlabel('Epoch')\n",
        "plt.legend()\n",
        "plt.show()"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "35-eEg3DsMXQ"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# Evaluating Model\n",
        "\n",
        "test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_sequences, test_Y)\n",
        "print('Test Loss :',test_loss)\n",
        "print('Test Accuracy :',test_accuracy)"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "R1YWF1uRsOel"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "source": [
        "# function to predict messages based on model\n",
        "# (should return list containing prediction and label, ex. [0.008318834938108921, 'ham'])\n",
        "\n",
        "intTolabel = {0: \"ham\", 1: \"spam\"}\n",
        "\n",
        "def predict_message(pred_text):\n",
        "  pred_text = remove_punctuations(pred_text)\n",
        "  pred_text = remove_stopwords(pred_text)\n",
        "\n",
        "  sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([pred_text])\n",
        "  sequence = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=max_len)\n",
        "\n",
        "  prediction = model.predict(sequence)[0]\n",
        "\n",
        "  label = \"ham\"\n",
        "  if prediction >= 0.5:\n",
        "      label = \"spam\"\n",
        "\n",
        "  print((prediction[0], label))\n",
        "  return (prediction[0], label)\n",
        "\n",
        "pred_text = \"how are you doing today?\"\n",
        "\n",
        "prediction = predict_message(pred_text)"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "id": "jSDSoc-psQN4"
      },
      "execution_count": null,
      "outputs": []
    },
    {
      "cell_type": "code",
      "execution_count": null,
      "metadata": {
        "id": "Dxotov85SjsC"
      },
      "outputs": [],
      "source": [
        "# Run this cell to test your function and model. Do not modify contents.\n",
        "\n",
        "def test_predictions():\n",
        "  test_messages = [\"how are you doing today\",\n",
        "                   \"sale today! to stop texts call 98912460324\",\n",
        "                   \"i dont want to go. can we try it a different day? available sat\",\n",
        "                   \"our new mobile video service is live. just install on your phone to start watching.\",\n",
        "                   \"you have won £1000 cash! call to claim your prize.\",\n",
        "                   \"i'll bring it tomorrow. don't forget the milk.\",\n",
        "                   \"wow, is your arm alright. that happened to me one time too\"\n",
        "                  ]\n",
        "\n",
        "  test_answers = [\"ham\", \"spam\", \"ham\", \"spam\", \"spam\", \"ham\", \"ham\"]\n",
        "  passed = True\n",
        "\n",
        "  for msg, ans in zip(test_messages, test_answers):\n",
        "    prediction = predict_message(msg)\n",
        "    if prediction[1] != ans:\n",
        "      passed = False\n",
        "\n",
        "  if passed:\n",
        "    print(\"You passed the challenge. Great job!\")\n",
        "  else:\n",
        "    print(\"You haven't passed yet. Keep trying.\")\n",
        "\n",
        "test_predictions()"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "colab": {
      "private_outputs": true,
      "provenance": [],
      "gpuType": "T4"
    },
    "kernelspec": {
      "display_name": "Python 3",
      "name": "python3"
    },
    "language_info": {},
    "accelerator": "GPU",
    "name": "SMS_Text_Classification_v2"
  },
  "nbformat": 4,
  "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is on the `metadata  - language_info` property. Just add the name of the language used in the kernel.

```json
"metadata": {
    ...
    "language_info": {
        "name": "python",
    }
    ...
}
```

https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbformat.html